# UITableView with Search Display Controller has slow initial scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with a Search Bar implemented. I am using a custom cell loaded from xib with 7 `UILabels`. When I enter data through the search bar, the initial scroll is always slow. I'll try to scroll down the searchResultsTableView and theres is a noticeable lag there. After that, scrolling through the table is fluid. The lag only appears upon first scroll of a new search.

I have also used the same custom cell on a different tableview and that seems to scroll fine with the same `cellForRowAtIndexPath` logic.

How can I make the lag on the searchResultsTableView go away?

Here is some code:

```
 //SchoolCell.h
 //All labels are hooked up from the SchoolCell.xib to SchoolCell.h
 //I haven't touched SchoolCell.m

 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *schoolNameLabel;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *locationLabel;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *averageGPALabel;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *averageLabel;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tuitionLabel;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *rankLabel;
```

In MainViewController.m (has a tableview with datasource and delegates hooked up)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SchoolCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
SchoolCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[SchoolCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];     
}

RankedSchool *rankedSchool = nil;
UnrankedSchool *unrankedSchool = nil;

if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        {case 0:
            cell.rankLabel.hidden = NO;
            rankedSchool = [self.filteredRankedSchoolsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.schoolNameLabel.text = rankedSchool.name;
            NSString* locationText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",rankedSchool.city, rankedSchool.state];
            cell.locationLabel.text = locationText;
            NSString* averageGPAText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Average GPA: %@",rankedSchool.gpaExpected];
            cell.averageGPALabel.text = averageGPAText;
            NSString* averageText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Average: %@",rankedSchool.minAvg];
            cell.averageLabel.text = averageText;
            NSString* tuitionText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",rankedSchool.nonresidentTuition];
            cell.tuitionLabel.text = tuitionText;
            NSString* rankText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rank: %@",rankedSchool.rank];
            cell.rankLabel.text = rankText;

            break;}
        {case 1:
            cell.rankLabel.hidden = YES;
            unrankedSchool = [self.filteredUnrankedSchoolsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.schoolNameLabel.text = unrankedSchool.name;
            NSString* locationText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",unrankedSchool.city, unrankedSchool.state];
            cell.locationLabel.text = locationText;
            NSString* averageGPAText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Average GPA: %@",unrankedSchool.gpaExpected];
            cell.averageGPALabel.text = averageGPAText;
            NSString* averageText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Average: %@",unrankedSchool.minAvg];
            cell.averageLabel.text = averageText;
            NSString* tuitionText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",unrankedSchool.nonresidentTuition];
            cell.tuitionLabel.text = tuitionText;

            break;}

        {default:
            break;}
    }

} else{
   //searchBar is firstResponder. User never interacts with tableview, only searchResultsTableView
}

return cell;

}
```